# Separate common cases of two Enums - Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I have two enums that have some cases that are common. Is there a way to separate the common cases in a protocol and the 2 enums to inherit them? (not necessary to be a protocol)

for example:

```
enum Test1: String {
    case common1 = "common1"
    case common2 = "common2"

    case new1 = "new1"
    case new2 = "new2"
}

enum Test2: String {
    case common1 = "common1"
    case common2 = "common2"

    case new3 = "new3"
}

// handles all the cases in Test1
func doSomethingA(value: Test1) {
    // code
}

// handles all the cases in Test2
func doSomethingB(value: Test2) {
    // code
}

// handles only! the common cases in Test1 and Test2
func doSomething(value: Test1, value1: Test2) {
    // code
    doSomethingA(value: value)
    doSomethingB(value: value1)
    // code
}
```

I have these two enums, `Test1` and `Test2`, with two cases being the same.

is it possible to modify the `func doSomething(value: Test1, value1: Test2)` so that I can pass only 1 parameter. Something like `func doSomething(value: Test)`? with `Test` having the common cases.

Comment: What would expect to happen if a parameter was used that wasn't a common case?  A more concrete use case would help the question be answered.

Comment: [and btw your `func doSomething(value: Test1, value1: Test2)` doesn't just handle the common cases of the two enums, it handles any cases of both of them.]

Comment: @flanker that's what I want to do with the `func doSomething`. That func should only be triggered/used for the common cases but right now I have to pass the `Test1` and `Test2`. I want the `func doSomething` to have only one parameter (protocol/enum, I don't know) and that parameter should be the common cases of the 2 enums `Test1` and `Test2`.

Comment: You may want that, but the compiler can't enforce that the instance values you pass into the method (whatever they may conform too) are the same.  You need to provide that logic somewhere, either before calling the method or inside it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry you can't do that because `Test1.common1` and `Test2.common1` are totally different types. You think `common1` and `common2` are the same but they aren't as I mentioned. Maybe we can make a compromise with these approaches:

1. Use `String` as the parameter

```
func doSomething(_ value: String) {
    switch value {
    case "common1":
        // do something with common1
        break
    case "common2":
        // do something with common2
        break
    default: break
    }
}
```

You can try like these `domSomething(test1.rawValue)` or `domSomething(test2.rawValue)`

2. Create a new enum type

```
enum Test {
    case common1
    case common2
    case others
    
    init(_ value: Test1) {
        switch value {
        case .common1:
            self = .common1
        case .common2:
            self = .common2
        default:
            self = .others
        }
    }
    
    init(_ value: Test2) {
        switch value {
        case .common1:
            self = .common1
        case .common2:
            self = .common2
        default:
            self = .others
        }
    }
}

func doSomething(_ test: Test) {
    switch test {
    case .common1:
        // do something with common1
        break
    case .common2:
        // do something with common2
        break
    default: break
    }
}
```

So you can try like this `doSomething(.init(test1))`

3. Merge two enums, like:

```
enum Test: String {
    case common1 = "common1"
    case common2 = "common2"

    case new1 = "new1"
    case new2 = "new2"
    case new3 = "new3"
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will check it later today. Especially the 2nd approach.